# Null value returned while finding entity by key in JPA

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa

I am developing app engine backend for android with two entities: user and item in one to many relationship. After inserting an item entity, I receive the inserted entity back in client app where the generated key of the item is converted to string and stored in database.Later, while trying to retrieve the same entity by passing the keystring to backend and then converting to key, I am getting null entity.What is the reason?

code to retrieve and delete item entity:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "removeItemById")
    public Item removeItemById(@Named("itemIdString") String idString) {
    //Getting key from the idstring..           
    Key key=KeyFactory.stringToKey(idString);
    EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
    try {
        //This is the line where only null value is returned...
        Item item = mgr.find(Item.class, key);
        mgr.remove(item);
        mgr.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        mgr.getTransaction().rollback();
        return null;
    }
    finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return new Item();
}
```

Item Entity:

```
   @Entity
   public class Item {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Key itemId;
 private String itemName;

 @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name="OWNER_ID")
 public User owner;

 ////Getters and setters......
  }
```

User Entity:

```
    @Entity
    public class User {
     @Id
    private String id;
    private  String userName;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity=com.example.xyz.Item.class,
      mappedBy="owner",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private ArrayList<Item> items;

   //getters and setters...


  }
```

Comment: so the entity doesn't exist with thet key. so likely you passed the wrong thing in to the method assuming an object does exist somewhere

Comment: @Neil I checked that several times.Entity does exists in the datastore.Yet only null is returned.is there any mistake in entity retrieval codes?The key is generated fine. It shows id,parent and its kind correctly.

Comment: we can't see the type of IdClass/Id in the entity. ANd look in the log for what query is invoked in the datastore. No idea what is "mistake in entity retrieval codes"

Comment: Updated entity class definitions.please check.

Comment: As @NeilStockton said, you are using Key as ID of your class, but there is no IdClass. Could you post the Key code?

Comment: @uaiHebert Key infact is the datastore key class:com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key.

Comment: the value passed to the method removeItemById is the string representataion of the key of the item entity.